# What "device" represents between socket and network

Tags: networking

Here is a question and an answer:

*How many times is the data in a message copied from a user process creating
it to it being sent onto the network?*

*Answer: two times*

*The data is copied once from user space to a socket buffer in the kernel space.
Then it is copied a second time from the socket buffer to the device.*

Can someone explain me this in more details? What "device" means here?

Comment: Network card? ...

Comment: The network card, or more specifically the Ethernet controller, aka EMAC.